# What motivates the choice of chain complex when calculating simplicial homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've been confused by the idea of homology for a while but I've decided to approach it because of an interesting paper I read recently.

When I was first introduced to it the lecturer was talking about formal linear combinations of the simplices with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}$. In the paper I read they computed homology using coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ What motivates the choice of a group when doing calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ allows one to disregard the orientation of simplices. This is used often in persistent homology to simplify computations. For instance, $C_n$ over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ would just be all possible combinations (the only non-trivial combinations are those with $1$ as a coefficient) of **single** $n$-dimensional simplices. It also follows that a chain’s inverse would be itself.

Comment: Are there any other commonly used groups?

Comment: Well, the definition of chain complex does not specify the ground ring that each module must take coefficients from. If you know about the universal coefficient theorem, then you’d know that homology systems that only vary the coefficients are already determined by the homology with $\Bbb{Z}$. Other conveniences like preferring fields or $\Bbb{Z}_2$ coefficients really only assist in making computations easier.

Comment: So to answer your question, I don’t know of any other commonly used rings. I feel that using $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{Q}$ would simply be to satisfy curiosity. Perhaps someone else will have a different perspective...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the homology groups for non-orientable surfaces such as the Klein bottle $K$. Then $H_2(K,\Bbb Z)=0$ but $H_2(K,\Bbb Z_2)\cong\Bbb Z_2$.
So in this case homology over $\Bbb Z_2$ sees more than that over $\Bbb Z$.
Using $\Bbb Z_2$ coefficients is often useful when one has non-orientability.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of reasons:

- Sometimes you don't have a choice of the group. De Rham cohomology, for example, is defined using differential equations on a smooth manifold and therefore naturally has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. (I've switched from talking about homology to cohomology, but they're closely related.)
- More complicated homology and cohomology theories can simliarly have natural coefficient groups, or even more complicated objects on which to act. The natural setting of group cohomology is a module on which the group acts, and more interesting modules than $\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial action can often give you more interesting or more powerful results. Sheaf cohomology is more complicated than I can get into here, but one way of describing it (which should not be taken seriously) is that it's cohomology with a continually varying coefficient group.
- As was mentioned above, different homology and cohomology coefficients can allow you detect different stuff going on in the underlying topological space.
- Poincare duality requires orientability. That means that it may not hold over $\mathbb{Z}$, but every manifold (or CW-complex, etc.) is orientable over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
- More complicated homology and cohomology theories often involving counting something according to sign (say, induced from some sort of orientation), and switching from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ eliminates the need to worry about it. (I think Floer homology falls into this category, but it's been a while.)

In practice, because of the universal coefficient theorem, the main groups people care about (for ordinary (co)homology, in the topological setting) are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Sometimes $\mathbb{Q}$ is useful to make a quick dimension argument rather than worrying about torsion.